# How do I disable mnemonics in GTK3?

Tags: 11.10, menu, gtk3, keyboard-accelerators

In Natty Narwhal I used to do some nifty tricks with `.gtkrc-2.0` to disable mnemonics (underlined menus) but now it's impossible. I assume in Oneiric Ocelot it will be something different because it uses GTK3.

I used to achieve this by adding the following lines:

```
gtk-enable-accels = 0
gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0
```

How can I get rid of the mnemonics in Oneiric Ocelot?

Comment: In Natty Narwhal I used this information: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7483418 In Oneiric Ocelot this doesn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: @jrg I contest this one. It's a cogent question, all requests for further information have been answered.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards user hasn't been seen since mid-nov. I'd define that as abandoned, its almost two months, and it has no answer.

Comment: @jrg The status of the original user doesn't matter. It's a real question that doesn't fit any of the close vote categories, and could be upvote-answered by the community.

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards I'd beg to differ, [this meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1981/6005) argues that we should vote after a few months. However, I'll let this be now, since we appear to be in a deadlock. :)

Answer (score 4):

To "disable" mnemonics for Nautilus 3.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 which uses GTK3:

1. Create the following path & file if it doesn't already exist.
   `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
2. Then add:
   `[Settings]`
   `gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0`
3. Then logout and log back in.

Sources:
* https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-March/msg00108.html
* https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html

p.s. Note that the GTK docs say you should have an environment variable called `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` but I didn't have one. I did have an existing `~/.config/gtk-3.0` folder and it appears it is looking there by default, without the environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

GTK3 doesn't use gtkrc anymore, but moved to styling with CSS. But there still is a way to change global settings.
Quoting from the [GTK reference](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkSettings.html):

> GTK+ reads default values for settings from settings.ini files in /etc/gtk-3.0 and $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gtk-3.0.

See that page for some more details.

I wonder if this works in Unity though, with the global menu. I don't know if these settings are adapted by it.

Answer (score 2):

After so long time and no answer found on my question I found it!

To hide mnemonics (keyboard accelerators) in GTK 3.x you just need to open:

```
/usr/share/themes/THEME_NAME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

Add the following line:

```
gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0
```

And save the file. Log out or change your theme with another one then change it back.
That's all. Nothing hard to do, only little research.

PS: Of course after update of ubuntu-light-themes package this will be lost and need to be redone again.

Answer (score 0):

add

`gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1`

in your theme settings:
`/usr/share/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

Comment: Editing an installed theme from /usr/share/themes is a BAD idea - as changes will be overwritten when new package is installed