# How to enable mnemonics in 12.04 and/or 14.04 GTK3?

Tags: gtk, wxpython

Word on the street is that "gtk-enable-mnemonics" has been deprecated since version 3.10, and I am not at all sure how to get my application to display mnemonics.

They will only display if I press the `alt` key.

Please see here:

- [wxPython Button Shortcut Accelerator How to '&spam' | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049406/wxpython-button-shortcut-accelerator-how-to-spam)

I have tried everything suggested in this article in regards to settings.ini, switching the bool to the opposite:

- [How do I disable mnemonics in GTK3? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76077/how-do-i-disable-mnemonics-in-gtk3)

Related:

- [GTK+ 3 Reference Manua | GNOME Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkSettings.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "disable" mnemonics for Nautilus 3.10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 which uses GTK3:

1. Create the following path & file if it doesn't already exist.
   `/home/YOURUSERNAME/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`
2. Then add:
   `[Settings]`
   `gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0`
3. Then logout and log back in.

Sources:

- [Is there an equivalent to .gtkrc-2.0 in gtk 3? | GNOME Mail Services](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-March/msg00108.html)
- [Settings: GTK+ 3 Reference Manual | GNOME Developer Center](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html)

p.s. Note that the GTK docs say you should have an environment variable called `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` but I didn't have one. I did have an existing `~/.config/gtk-3.0` folder and it appears it is looking there by default, without the environment variable.

Comment: I'm really confused by this answer since the question seems to be asking how to *enable* always showing mnemonics, but this answer talks about disabling them.

Comment: Good point, I have no idea why I posted this as an answer then.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like GTK+-3 lost the "gtk-auto-mnemonics" setting after version 3.8 (starting from version 3.10 on).

The following patch for 3.14.4 should re-enable "gtk-auto-mnemonics". It will probably also work with other GTK+-3 versions like 3.16. After compiling, you'll only need these files (first two are symlinks):

```
libgtk-3.so -> libgtk-3.so.0.1400.4
libgtk-3.so.0 -> libgtk-3.so.0.1400.4
libgtk-3.so.0.1400.4
```

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.14/gtk+-3.14.4.tar.xz

You can easily start using the compiled stuff by this (replace `lib64` with `lib` if necessary):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/folder/where/you/installed/lib64 file-roller
```

-

Don't know why, but it looks like the GTK+ developers became really great in removing code which provided useful features like this...!!!

If any GTK+ developer reads this: How did those code-lines hurt anyone or why where they removed???

If someone's interested in the original commit:

- https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/7e3a494fac62140f466fc43f6cc061215953e9b1
- https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/7e3a494fac62140f466fc43f6cc061215953e9b1.patch

Looks like the GTK+ people had a feature-remove run at that time:

- https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/425e977bb65a52c05fbc2b643acf32aec4bc477f
- https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/7b66956e63f4cd85fc72bf51778596c9b1b83c28

==========

```
diff -ur gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtklabel.c gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtklabel.c
--- gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtklabel.c  2014-10-21 16:20:55.000000000 +0200
+++ gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtklabel.c  2015-05-06 23:01:45.447209817 +0200
@@ -2561,11 +2561,12 @@

   if (with_uline)
     {
-      gboolean enable_mnemonics = TRUE;
-      gboolean auto_mnemonics = TRUE;
+      gboolean enable_mnemonics;
+      gboolean auto_mnemonics;

       g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (GTK_WIDGET (label)),
                     "gtk-enable-mnemonics", &enable_mnemonics,
+                    "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics,
                     NULL);

       if (!(enable_mnemonics && priv->mnemonics_visible &&
@@ -2775,8 +2776,8 @@
 {
   GtkLabelPrivate *priv = label->priv;
   PangoAttrList *attrs;
-  gboolean enable_mnemonics = TRUE;
-  gboolean auto_mnemonics = TRUE;
+  gboolean enable_mnemonics;
+  gboolean auto_mnemonics;

   if (priv->pattern_set)
     return;
@@ -2784,8 +2785,9 @@
   if (is_mnemonic)
     {
       g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (GTK_WIDGET (label)),
-                    "gtk-enable-mnemonics", &enable_mnemonics,
-                    NULL);
+           "gtk-enable-mnemonics", &enable_mnemonics,
+           "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics,
+           NULL);

       if (enable_mnemonics && priv->mnemonics_visible && pattern &&
           (!auto_mnemonics ||
diff -ur gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkmain.c gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkmain.c
--- gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkmain.c   2014-10-21 16:20:55.000000000 +0200
+++ gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkmain.c   2015-05-06 22:47:35.375311109 +0200
@@ -1717,18 +1717,26 @@
           ((event->key.state & (gtk_accelerator_get_default_mod_mask ()) & ~(GDK_RELEASE_MASK|GDK_MOD1_MASK)) == 0) &&
           !GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL (grab_widget))
         {
-          gboolean mnemonics_visible;
-          GtkWidget *window;
+          gboolean auto_mnemonics;

-          mnemonics_visible = (event->type == GDK_KEY_PRESS);
+          g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (grab_widget),
+                        "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics, NULL);

-          window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel (grab_widget);
-          if (GTK_IS_WINDOW (window))
+          if (auto_mnemonics)
             {
-              if (mnemonics_visible)
-                _gtk_window_schedule_mnemonics_visible (GTK_WINDOW (window));
-              else
-                gtk_window_set_mnemonics_visible (GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
+              gboolean mnemonics_visible;
+              GtkWidget *window;
+
+              mnemonics_visible = (event->type == GDK_KEY_PRESS);
+
+              window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel (grab_widget);
+              if (GTK_IS_WINDOW (window))
+                {
+                  if (mnemonics_visible)
+                    _gtk_window_schedule_mnemonics_visible (GTK_WINDOW (window));
+                  else
+                    gtk_window_set_mnemonics_visible (GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
+                }
             }
         }
       /* else fall through */
diff -ur gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkmenushell.c gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkmenushell.c
--- gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkmenushell.c  2014-08-15 16:38:05.000000000 +0200
+++ gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkmenushell.c  2015-05-06 22:53:03.442086931 +0200
@@ -898,9 +898,17 @@
 _gtk_menu_shell_update_mnemonics (GtkMenuShell *menu_shell)
 {
   GtkMenuShell *target;
+  gboolean auto_mnemonics;
   gboolean found;
   gboolean mnemonics_visible;

+  g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (GTK_WIDGET (menu_shell)),
+                "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics,
+                NULL);
+
+  if (!auto_mnemonics)
+    return;
+
   target = menu_shell;
   found = FALSE;
   while (target)
diff -ur gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkwindow.c gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkwindow.c
--- gtk+-3.14.4.old/gtk/gtkwindow.c 2014-10-21 16:20:55.000000000 +0200
+++ gtk+-3.14.4.new/gtk/gtkwindow.c 2015-05-06 22:59:47.780956630 +0200
@@ -5878,6 +5878,8 @@
   GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW (widget);
   GtkWindowPrivate *priv = window->priv;
   GdkWindow *gdk_window;
+  gboolean auto_mnemonics;
+  GtkPolicyType visible_focus;
   GList *link;

   if (!gtk_widget_is_toplevel (widget))
@@ -5966,10 +5968,15 @@
         }
     }

-  /* if mnemonics visible is not already set
+  /* if auto-mnemonics is enabled and mnemonics visible is not already set
    * (as in the case of popup menus), then hide mnemonics initially
    */
-  if (!priv->mnemonics_visible_set)
+  g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (widget),
+                "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics,
+                "gtk-visible-focus", &visible_focus,
+                NULL);
+
+  if (auto_mnemonics && !priv->mnemonics_visible_set)
     gtk_window_set_mnemonics_visible (window, FALSE);

   /* inherit from transient parent, so that a dialog that is
@@ -7834,6 +7841,7 @@
               GdkEventFocus *event)
 {
   GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW (widget);
+  gboolean auto_mnemonics;

   /* It appears spurious focus in events can occur when
    *  the window is hidden. So we'll just check to see if
@@ -7845,7 +7853,9 @@
       _gtk_window_set_has_toplevel_focus (window, TRUE);
       _gtk_window_set_is_active (window, TRUE);

-      if (gtk_window_has_mnemonic_modifier_pressed (window))
+      g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (widget),
+                    "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics, NULL);
+      if (auto_mnemonics && gtk_window_has_mnemonic_modifier_pressed (window))
         _gtk_window_schedule_mnemonics_visible (window);
     }

@@ -7857,12 +7867,16 @@
                GdkEventFocus *event)
 {
   GtkWindow *window = GTK_WINDOW (widget);
+  gboolean auto_mnemonics;

   _gtk_window_set_has_toplevel_focus (window, FALSE);
   _gtk_window_set_is_active (window, FALSE);

   /* set the mnemonic-visible property to false */
-  gtk_window_set_mnemonics_visible (window, FALSE);
+  g_object_get (gtk_widget_get_settings (widget),
+                "gtk-auto-mnemonics", &auto_mnemonics, NULL);
+  if (auto_mnemonics)
+    gtk_window_set_mnemonics_visible (window, FALSE);

   return FALSE;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I was changing the wrong theme. Oops.

Steps followed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095212/2026508

Change from: `gtk-auto-mnemonics = 0`  <---- Disabled

Change to: `gtk-auto-mnemonics = 1`    <---- Enabled

In GTK3 change in settings.ini:
`/usr/share/themes/CURRENT_THEME_NAME/gtk3.0/settings.ini`

In GTK2 change in gtkrc:
`/usr/share/themes/CURRENT_THEME_NAME/gtk2.0/gtkrc`

But make sure it is the correct/current theme.