# Disable Alt Gr shortcuts to enable third level keyboard access

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a custom keyboard setup that I use, with 3rd level keys that appear when you press the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> button and another key.

The problem is that I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key is used for menu shortcuts instead, so I can't use it any more for my purpose.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I don't mind losing the shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1113420) [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1735533)

> To disable mnemonics you should create (if it doesn't already exist)
>   `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. This file should contain the line `gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0` (you can add other GTK settings if you'd like). Then, restart for the changes to take effect (you may be able to log out then log in instead).

Comment: Those instructions don't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: This didn't work for me on Nautilus on 14.04. I posted an answer to a similar question here http://askubuntu.com/a/569303/11929