# Disable Alt-menu in Openbox?

Tags: openbox

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 w/ Openbox 3.6.1. When I press Alt, some applications shows their menu. How I can disable this behavior, so Alt won't do anything?

Comment: @DKBose Firefox-based (Firefox itself, Komodo, etc.)

Comment: I'm using my own keybindings for everything and I don't use window's menu bar a lot. More over, I just want to make Alt don't do anything, but I would still assign another key (Super_R for example) to open the menu bar of any application.

Comment: @DKBose I dunno. It's something that I was able to do in Unity but not in Openbox.

Comment: Thought there's a setting for that.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Openbox, but everything to do with GTK. Supposedly, you add `gtk-enable-mnemonics=0` to your settings.ini or your gtkrc, but this hasn't worked for me. I'll try one more thing and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly this can be disabled by changing a setting in the gtkrc or settings.ini files, for GTK 2 and 3 respectively. The option is [gtk-enable-mnemonics](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-enable-mnemonics), it has been deprecated, but the documentation states it still should be possible to use it.
[image: gtk-enable-mnemonics documentation entry]

However, it really was removed from GTK, [as this other answer states](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471201/how-to-enable-mnemonics-in-12-04-and-or-14-04-gtk3/477994#answer-620316), [you can view the commit's diff here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/7e3a494fac62140f466fc43f6cc061215953e9b1).

There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1113420) for it in Nautilus' launchpad, so maybe Ubuntu will make a patch one day, although I doubt it.